# Invalid format error with Joda Time timezone pattern

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, date-format

I don't understand why the following lines of code are not working with Joda Time:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.
                                              forPattern("yyyyMMddhhmmss Z");
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.print(now));
DateTime d = x.parseDateTime("200906031633 -0300");
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "200006031633 -0300" is malformed at " -0300" at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:683)

What is strange for me is that the `System.out.prinln(dateTimeFormatter.print(now));` it's fine and prints according to the pattern:
    `20110131101805 +0100`

What is the problem? From what I read on [Joda Time's pattern syntax](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), the pattern seems correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks guys! What a stupid mistake :) Thank you for your help, I think without it I would have wasted another hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your pattern should use "HH" not "hh" if you expect it to parse that value.  Secondly, you'll need to include seconds in the value as well.

E.g.

```
DateTime d = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("20090603163300 -0300");
```

Comment: Yeah, just caught that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are missing seconds in the **200906031633 -0300**. It works if I add seconds to that as shown below: (200906031633"00" -0300)

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss Z");    
DateTime d = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("20090603163300 -0300");
```